# MySQL how to solve One-to-one relation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a One-to-One Chat implementation with MySQL.
The goal is to got for one user all unique Conversations with the last message. Even I'm using MAX on the primary key and group by 2nd column MySQL reject this.

The below query give the error: Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'm.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause;

I'm using MySQL Version 8.

What I'm missing here?

Message table

```
id | member_a_id | member_a_status | member_b_id | member_b_status | conversation_id | content | created_dt
```

Conversation table

```
id | member_a_id | member_a_status | member_b_id | member_b_status | conversation_id | content | created_dt | last_activity_dt
```

Query:

```
SELECT
  MAX(m.id) AS msgid, m.*
FROM
  message m
WHERE m.conversation_id IN
  (SELECT
    c.id
  FROM
    conversation c
  WHERE (
      c.member_a_id = 600
      AND c.member_a_status NOT IN (0, 3)
    )
    OR (
      c.member_b_id = 600
      AND c.member_b_status NOT IN (0, 3)
    ))
GROUP BY m.conversation_id
ORDER BY m.id DESC;
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff will add in next minutes sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without sample data, your question is a bit hard to follow.  However, you should be using window functions if you are using MySQL 8+.  The query would look something like this:

```
SELECT cm.*
FROM (SELECT m.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.conversation_id ORDE BY m.id DESC) as seqnum
      FROM message m JOIN
           conversion c
           ON m.conversation_id = c.conversation_id
      WHERE 600 IN (c.member_a_id, c.member_b_id) AND
            c.member_a_status NOT IN (0, 3)
     ) mc
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you, it deliver the result but it needs 24 sec on my test data set and make it not usable, when I remove m.* or sey ANY_VALUE and use one column with my above query it took 240ms.

Comment: I was able to got 500ms instead 24sec execution time when changed WHERE to the way I have it on my Query. I'm going to try to speed it more up, but as I'm now on 500ms I'm optimistic to reach low 200ms on my test data set (20M messages, 4m conversation and result set of 600 records).